# ASP Menu totally dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sharepoint, menu

I want to create an ASP:Menu containing my entire website (or almost). I saw that I can use the Sitemap or XML files.
But the question is: What happens when I add a new page to my website?
Is there any way to make the process dynamic?

BTW: The Menu is to be used with Sharepoint. There are any solutions through Sharepoint?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be use a dynamic [SiteMap provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider.aspx) of some kind - I believe that SharePoint has one of those out of the box in the form of the `PortalSiteMapProvider` - this provides you with a pre-cached SiteMap that you can use in the various ASP.NET controls that expect a SiteMap.

Comment: Thank you for you reply! May I use it to rewrite the XML DataSource (used to populate ASP:Menu) everytime a site/page is created and then update the menu?

Comment: If the pages/sites you are creating are Sharepoint pages/sites, then the PortalSiteMapProvider should update as needed when new pages are published. You should then be able to reference that in your menu as far as I know.